# Menu of PGN-Viewer is displayed behind elements of the sidebar

Tags: bug, user-interface, specific-site

The menu of the PGN-Viewer on https://chess.stackexchange.com/ is (partly) displayed behind the elements of the sidebar (Related Posts, Ads,...). I have checked that using latest Chrome and Internet Explorer 11.

I´m have no account on that site and visited as a guest. [Example question for reference](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/13372/outcome-of-a-game-in-case-of-an-illegal-checkmate)

[image]

Comment: While a valid bug, this is really specific to the chess site and belongs on its meta.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sure. but I do not have an account on that page and I don´t want to create one for this case.

Comment: Fair enough, SE employee with a diamond here can migrate, I guess.